# Intuit Anywhere : Invalid Signature Error 401

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am tying to fetch Accounts Before a certain date
I use the following code

```
TimeZoneInfo pst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
        DateTime now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(new DateTime(2012, 06, 30), pst);
        accountQuery.CreateTime = now;
        accountQuery.SpecifyOperatorOption(FilterProperty.CreateTime, 
               FilterOperatorType.BEFORE);
        accountQuery.PageNumber = 1;
        accountQuery.ResultsPerPage = 100;
        string a = Response.ToString();
        List<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account> accounts =
           accountQuery.ExecuteQuery<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account>(context)
              .ToList<Intuit.Ipp.Data.Qbo.Account>();
```

But I get an error Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid

Comment: What language is this? Seems like C#; is that correct?

Comment: It sounds like when you are building your OAuth signature, it is not including the body.

Comment: I tested this code with the .NET DevKit v2.1.12.0 (https://nuget.org/packages/IPPDotNetDevKit/) and it works.  What version are you using?  Also, Can you log the request/response XML? (http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0200_DevKits/0100_IPP_.NET_DevKit/0600_Logging)

Comment: Yes it is C#.  My request body is Filter=CreateTime :BEFORE: 2012-06-29T15:00:00+02:00&PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=100 and Response is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd"><Message>Unauthorized OAuth Token: signature_invalid</Message><ErrorCode>401</ErrorCode><Cause>SERVER</Cause></FaultInfo>

Comment: Peter: I have also update the solution to  .NET DevKit v2.1.12.0 but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Are you able to make other API calls?  Is it only calls with the filter body that you are having trouble with?

It seems that the OAuth tokens are invalid, and this isn't related to the DevKit.  Please try the OAuth tokens in the API explorer @ apiexplorer.developer.intuit.com with any call (e.g., CompanyMetaData GET) to see if they are valid.

Comment: Yes if i take out the filters then it works ok. I checked OAuth token with the API explorer and they are ok.